# reorder columns dynamically in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to reorder columns in R. Here is the situation:

I have 9 columns right now: `A-NP F-WR K-WR H-ER Q-ER B-NP C-NP Z-WR X-ER`

The rule is NP > WR > ER. So columns with NP in name should be the first columns. Within columns in the same group, it's alphabetic order.

So the desired output will be:

```
A-NP B-NP C-NP F-WR K-WR Z-WR H-ER Q-ER X-ER
```

The columns are in this format (something-NP/WR/ER) but it's different every time so I want to create something that can order these columns dynamically.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
# create an example data frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 9, nrow = 0))
names(df) <- c("A-NP", "F-WR", "K-WR", "H-ER", "Q-ER", "B-NP", "C-NP", "Z-WR", "X-ER")

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  # sort in alphabetical order
  select(sort(names(.))) %>%
  # sort based on the rule
  select(contains("NP"), contains("WR"), contains("ER"))
# [1] A-NP B-NP C-NP F-WR K-WR Z-WR H-ER Q-ER X-ER
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution using `?grep()` -

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 9, nrow = 0))
names(df) <- c("F-WR", "K-WR", "H-ER", "Q-ER", "B-NP", "C-NP", "Z-WR", "X-ER", "A-NP")

df[, c(sort(grep("NP", names(df), value = T)), 
       sort(grep("WR", names(df), value = T)), 
       sort(grep("ER", names(df), value = T))
      )
  ]


[1] A-NP B-NP C-NP F-WR K-WR Z-WR H-ER Q-ER X-ER
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```